# Finding a sequence $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ where $a_{n}$ converges and $b_{n}$ is unbounded, and $a_{n}b_{n}$ converges

Tags: proof-verification

So the question is to state without proof $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ such that $a_{n}$ converges, $b_{n}$ is unbounded and $a_{n}b_{n}$ converges.

I chose $a_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_{n} = (-1)^n$

Then $a_{n}b_{n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Am I correct?

Comment: $b_n=(-1)^n$ has no limit, but it is not unbounded.

Comment: maybe choose $b_n=n$?

Comment: What about $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $b_n=n$?

Comment: Here $|b_n| =1$, so it is not unbounded. Maybe choose something as suggested by @Mastream

Comment: I'm confused, from a previous question I asked, I was led to believe that $(-1)^n$ is indeed bounded. Could you explain in a bit more detail why it isn't?

Comment: Nevermind I'm being stupid, thanks for the answers I get it now

Comment: @mrnovice; you could write up your answer so we have one.  The FAQ explicitly permits this if you find the answer along the way.  After some delay you will be able to accept it as well.

Comment: In fact, the following is true : Given any sequence $a_n$ converging to zero, there exists an unbounded sequence $b_n$ such that $a_n b_n$ converges. Can you think about this?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Do we choose $b_{n}=\frac{1}{a_{n}}$?

Comment: Exactly. So you've got your example. Even more, I think there exists $b_n$ unbounded such that $a_nb_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, I now know that I made a silly error in choosing $b_{n} = (-1)^n$ which is bounded rather than unbounded, since $|b_{n}|=1$. Therefore instead choosing $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $b_{n} = n$ would satisfy the original question, since $a_n b_n = \frac{1}{n}$ which converges.